# Python Kivy error: Unable to get a Window, abort

Tags: python, anaconda, kivy, shader

I'm tired trying to fix this error, can someone help me?
I fixed the kivy fatal error first with adding a variable in the variables environment in the user variable(the variable's name is: KIVY_GL_BACKEND and it value is: angle_sdl2)
I am using anaconda python 3.8.5 windows 7

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world', text_size = 32)

MyApp().run()
```

And the error is:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\FARHAN\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-07-22_15.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\FARHAN\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\FARHAN\anaconda3\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Activate GLES2/ANGLE context
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <angle_sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0.8613f4946861)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Google Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'ANGLE (Famille de jeu de puces Express Mobile Intel(R) 45 (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1) Direct3D11 vs_4_0 ps_4_0)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00 (ANGLE 2.1.0.8613f4946861)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[ERROR  ] [Shader      ] GL error 1282
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] program: <Failed to create D3D shaders.>
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - Exception: Shader didnt link, check info log.
  File "C:\Users\FARHAN\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 70, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "C:\Users\FARHAN\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Users\FARHAN\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 982, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "C:\Users\FARHAN\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 311, in create_window
    super(WindowSDL, self).create_window()
  File "C:\Users\FARHAN\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1268, in create_window
    self.render_context = RenderContext()
  File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 777, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__
  File "kivy\graphics\shader.pyx", line 184, in kivy.graphics.shader.Shader.__init__
  File "kivy\graphics\shader.pyx", line 701, in kivy.graphics.shader.Shader.vs.__set__
  File "kivy\graphics\shader.pyx", line 557, in kivy.graphics.shader.Shader.build_vertex
  File "kivy\graphics\shader.pyx", line 587, in kivy.graphics.shader.Shader.link_program

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: try re-installing kivy.

Comment: I also tried that, I re-installed anaconda and kivy the same error comes

Answer (score 0):

In cmd go to python34 and then to Scripts and install the following:

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
pip install kivy.deps.angle
pip install kivy
```

Comment: thank you for helping me, but when I run my code again after doing all these steps in the cmd, I got this error:`OSError: [WinError 127] La procédure spécifiée est introuvable: 'C:\\Users\\FARHAN\\anaconda3\\share\\gstreamer\\bin'`

Answer (score 0):

this helped me:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'vsync', -1)
Config.write()
```

run two times

Comment: Or, even better, delete the config.ini file altogether. It's stored in c:\Users\[username]\.kivy\. It has all video/window settings, and in my case, some of these settings prevented Kivy to start. And this file is not removed on "pip uninstall kivy" or deinstalling Python itself. Manual removal of this file will force Kivy to create it from scratch with default settings which in my case solved the problem.